Why does Flush+Reload not work on the c906 CPU when Evict+Reload does?
I'm studying this paper on different side-channel attacks on Risc-V cores: https://misc0110.net/files/riscv_attacks_sp23.pdf
The authors introduce a new attack called Flush+Fault which works around the limitation that makes Flush+Reload impossible, no shared I-Cache and D-Cache (harvard architecture).
So if I understand correctly, the "reload" step is not possible on that core, which is why they do Fault instead.
Further down, they successfully execute the "Evict+Reload" attack on the same core. So my question is: Why does the Reload step work for "Evict+Reload", when it was impossible for Flush+Reload?

This is a quote from Page 9
..The advantage of Evict+Reload over Flush+Reload is that no unprivileged flush instruction is required, as the target address is evicted, making Evict+ Reload viable on both the C906 and U74..

Yes, but the C906 has a vendor specific flush instructions which are used in the Flush+fault variant. It is briefly explained here, but I don't fully understand: https://youtu.be/HCZ6DCu2ciE?t=1134
They say Flush+Reload does not work because of separate I-Cache and D-Cache, which prevents the reload step. But then again, Evict+Reload works. So what is the difference in the "Reload" step?
